# ValueError: cannot assign mismatch length to masked array while using dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have made a program where I'm converting raw file from my bank account for credit card transactions to a cleansed file with some new columns.

I'm replacing a column values based on my dictionary. Dictionary has 5 rows, where as the data frame has variable rows. It is to further group the data into types.

I'm also filtering the data so using masking aswell.

replace code

```
t_type = df2['Transaction'].replace(mappingforcc.load_dictionary.dictionary, inplace=True)
```

while debugging, when i make the rows equal in dictionary and the dataframe, code runs smooth without any issue. but when there is mismatch among both, I'm getting following error:

ValueError: cannot assign mismatch length to masked array

I even made a function so that i dont have two data frames in my original code as I'm creating dictionary from an excel file.

Despite several searches, unable to resolve it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: I have found the issue, the problem is that I'm creating dictionary from the following code

```
load_dictionary.dictionary2  = df_dict.groupby(['Transactions'])['Type'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

due to which I'm getting the following output in dictionary as there are multiple rows in the sheet.

```
{'Adv Tax FCY Tran 1%-F': ['Recoverable - Adv. Tax', 'Recoverable - Adv. Tax', 'Recoverable - Adv. Tax', 'Recoverable - Adv. Tax']
```

Due to which, if another transaction of 'Adv Tax FCY Tran 1%-F' appears, python cannot interpret as it tries to find a value in it.

Need help to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, removed duplicates from the dictionary excel file.

My file had multiple rows for each of the lines, hence the group by function incorporated all in dictionary. And when there was a mismatch in numbers, i was getting the error of mismatch.

I also created a function to create my own directory to come around it though but didn't use it as it worked like a charm after i removed duplicates.

I'm a beginner at programming but still sharing the function (converted to code for ease of sharing and easier for everyone to use)

```
import openpyexcel 
from openpyexcel import load_workbook
import ast

file_path = r"filepath.xlsx"
df = openpyexcel.load_workbook(file_path)

ws = df['Sheet1'] #Enter your sheet name or automate using multiple functions in openpyxl
dictionary = "{"

for i in range(2,ws.max_row): #Since i have a header too, therefore started from 2nd Row
    dictionary = dictionary + '"' +  (ws[('A'+str(i))].value) + '"' + ":" + '"' + (ws[('B'+str(i))].value) + '"' #I have used column A and B, you can change accordingly.
    if i != (ws.max_row-1):
         dictionary =  dictionary + ',' 

dictionary =  dictionary + '}'
dictionary = ast.literal_eval(dictionary)
```

This issue wasn't at all a waste of time, learnt alot of things along the way

Comment: good job on solving the problem, you might want to read [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary) on how to properly use dictionaries